# Multistep Form in django

Tags: django, forms

I was working with normal crispy forms in django. I changed the form to multi step form, now the submit doesnt work. So when i click on submit data  doesnt get stored in the db.
This is how the updated template looks like: index.html
**index.html**

```
<ul id="progressbar">
            <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
            <li>Social Profiles</li>
            <li>Personal Details</li>
          </ul>
            <!-- fieldsets -->
          <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Help me know you better</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
            {{ form.associate_image|as_crispy_field}}
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
            {{ form.title|as_crispy_field}}
            {{ form.client|as_crispy_field }}
            {{ form.lob|as_crispy_field }}
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
            {{ form.gender|as_crispy_field }}
            {{ form.phone_number|as_crispy_field }}
            <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit-award" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
         </fieldset>
```

This is the view function :
**views.py**

```
@login_required
def save_information(request):

    associate_id = id_to_numeric(request.user.username)
    ldap = Ldap()
    current_user = UserDetails.objects.filter(associate_nbr=associate_id)
    if current_user.exists():
        current_user.delete()
    associate_details = ldap.search(associate_id=associate_id)[0]
    details = UserDetails(
        associate_name=associate_details['name'],
        associate_nbr=associate_id,
        associate_email=associate_details['email'],
        associate_department_id=id_to_numeric(associate_details['department']),
        associate_mgr=associate_details['xxx'],
        associate_exec=associate_details['xxx'],
        associate_org=associate_details['org'],
        associate_image=request.FILES['associate_image'],
        gender=request.POST['gender'],
        title=request.POST['title'],
        client=request.POST['client'],
        lob=request.POST['lob'],
        phone_number=request.POST['phone_number'] ,
    )

    details.save()

    return redirect('/?submit=true')
```

Comment: What do you get when you set a breakpoint and look at `request.POST`? (or print it) What is the actual problem? Are there any errors? Does the redirect happen? You should be more specific about what you see. You don't even say if `save_information` is actually called.

Comment: And where's the `<form>` tag anyway?

Comment: The form is not getting submitted